# Nav bar won't stay in header when made smaller. How can I achieve this?

Tags: html, css, navigation, containers, nav

The issue that I'm having is that my menu bar won't remain within the header.

I'm trying to design a single page but I can not work out how to keep the nav menu from dropping out of the blue header when the window is made smaller.

I've tried using `min-height`, `overflow` etc, but I think I may be missing something obvious.

Can I have some help/advice please?

Thanks,

Anish

**HTML**

```
    <header>
        <div class="containernav">
        <img src="Images/VAC_Modern_LOGO_V3_optometrists.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#eyecare">Eye Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>

    <body>

       <div id="home">
            <div class="textbox">
                <h3>lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem</p>

    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
    @charset "utf-8";

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background: rgba(4, 26, 125, 0.5);
    }

    .containernav {
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    img {
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
    }

    header {
        background: rgb(4, 26, 125);
    }

    header::after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .logo {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }

    nav {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
    }

    nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 70px;
        padding-top: 33px;
        position: relative;
    }

    nav a {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color: rgba(249, 29, 0, 0.5);
    }

    nav a::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 5px;
        width: 0%;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
    }

    nav a:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
    }

    button {
        background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5);
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        padding 100px 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `position: absolute;` on the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the code below.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background: rgba(4, 26, 125, 0.5);
    }

    .containernav {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    }

    img {
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
    }

    header {
        background: rgb(4, 26, 125);
    }

    header::after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .logo {
        padding: 5px 0;
    }

    nav {
    }

    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 70px;
        padding-top: 33px;
        position: relative;
    }

    nav a {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color: rgba(249, 29, 0, 0.5);
    }

    nav a::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 5px;
        width: 0%;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
    }

    nav a:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
    }

    button {
        background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5);
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        padding 100px 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="containernav">
        <img src="Images/VAC_Modern_LOGO_V3_optometrists.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#eyecare">Eye Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>

    <body>

       <div id="home">
            <div class="textbox">
                <h3>lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem</p>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navBar is pretty messy, I'd recommend creating it simply using *width %* and *float*. Here's a basic navBar, it will resize and always stay on one line.

You can do this using pure CSS, just make sure the element you are wanting to show is directly after the parent.

```css
.navTitle {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.navTitle:hover .moreInfo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.moreInfo {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 1</p>
 <p class="moreInfo">More info 1</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 2</p>
 <p class="moreInfo">More info 2</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 3</p>
 <p class="moreInfo">More info 3</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 4</p>
 <p class="moreInfo">More info 4</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 5</p>
 <p class="moreInfo">More info 5</p>
</div>
```